# If BIOS is stored on a flash memory chip, what is the purpose of ROM now?

Tags: memory, bios

According to Wikipedia, in older computers the BIOS firmware was stored on the ROM chip which was attached to the motherboard. However, nowadays BIOS is stored on a flash memory chip on the motherboard. So if the instructions to boot up the PC and such are on the BIOS flash memory chip, what is the ROM chip used for in modern times?

Comment: ROM "chips" have multiple applications other than in personal computers. They are used in many devices, game cartridges (think Nintendo 3DS) for one, where it is preferable NOT to allow the end user the capability of changing the code.

Comment: It's not "the ROM". ROM is a kind of memory/chip: "Read Only Memory". And there are still applications for this

Comment: ROM in an individual chip is practically nonexistent.  But ROM integrated with a CPU and peripherals, aka System on a chip (SoC) is widespread.  The typical ARM SoC has ROM to store startup code and a bootstrap program.  Bugs in the ROM code cannot be fixed/replaced until the mask is changed for next chip revision.